# Flutter Sound Package Show Error detected in pubspec.yaml: No file or variants found for asset: packages/flutter_sound_web/howler/howler.js

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: packages/flutter_sound_web/howler/howler.js.

This asset was included from package flutter_sound_web.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can you share your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: I only Import flutter sound pkg nothing else i do with pubspec and no code. BUt showing this error . when I remove this pkg build successful

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted flutter_sound_web plugin from flutter plugin folder and build successful